# Upgrade hell - Emotion with Project storm React Diagrams

Tags: reactjs, typescript, emotion

I've been stuck for 2 days on this.

I made the mistake of upgrading [React Diagrams](https://github.com/projectstorm/react-diagrams) and started getting this error in Emotion Cache Browser that I can't find how to fix whenever I load the component with the diagram.

[image]

Please help!

Dependencies include

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "@emotion/babel-plugin": "^11.2.0",
    "@emotion/cache": "^11.1.3",
    "@emotion/react": "11.1.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "11.1.5",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-scripts-ts": "4.0.8",
    "typescript": "3.8.3",
     ....
  },
  "dependencies": {
"@projectstorm/react-diagrams": "6.5.0",
"emotion": "^11.0.0",
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-app-rewired": "1.6.2",
"react-dom": "17.0.1",
 ...
```

},

Weirdly I can't even revert to a working example, if I load the commit before making this change it's telling me it needs to import @emotion/react when it never needed that library before.. adding it starts off an upgrade chain that leads here anyway.

Comment: `Weirdly I can't even revert to a working example`: You can if you know which "version" (of React-Diagrams) it worked with. And you can find that out by looking in (working) package.json (or better package-lock.json or yarn.lock). And, you can do all of this easily if you are using Versioning tool like git.

Comment: yea doing all that. Have reverted and I'm getting other errors related to emotion/react which weren't there before

Comment: Now, check which library is adding "emotion/react" as its dependency? Then, you need to find out what should be the correct version of emotion/react.

Comment: react-diagrams. I have that already